# How do you disable an upstart service in ubuntu 10.10?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, upstart

In 10.10 upstart is being used instead of sysvinit.

It's possible to remove annoying upstart services which you do not want by removing the appropriate file in /etc/init/blah.conf

However, this seems a heavy handed approach. How do you correctly configure upstart to be able to selectively turn these services on and off via the command line?

As a practical example, the answers listed here to turn gdm off using rcconf no longer work:
[How do I prevent GDM from running at boot on Ubuntu?](https://superuser.com/questions/105581/how-do-i-prevent-gdm-from-running-at-boot-on-ubuntu/266039)

Comment: Nb. Apparently some versions of ubuntu have a 'services' item in the menu of the graphical desktop that allows this to be configured. That is not present on mine. I'm specifically looking for a command line solution.

Comment: The most updated answer is on [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/whats-the-recommend-way-to-enable-disable-services/20347#20347). *Read the comments too!*

Comment: This is now [documented](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/) in the paragraph [Disabling a Job from Automatically Starting](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#disabling-a-job-from-automatically-starting).

Comment: @Marcello Hm... was there a point to saying that? The 'most updated answer' is still the same answer. remove the file or delete the first few lines of it manually.

Comment: the newest solution is `echo manual >> /etc/init/<service>.override`, and this is mentioned only in the comments (and in the official documentation). I did not found it easily, that's why I mentioned it here.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you look in /etc/init.d you will notice that any services that are configured through upstart are just symbolic links to /lib/init/upstart so removing them from /etc/init.d just removes the link - not the script.

If you want an interface to this you can install the `chkconfig` package (`apt-get install chkconfig`) which gives a useful command line tool:

```
# chkconfig --list
acpi-support              0:off  1:off  2:on   3:on   4:on   5:on   6:off
acpid                     0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
alsa-mixer-save           0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
anacron                   0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
apache2                   0:off  1:off  2:on   3:on   4:on   5:on   6:off
apparmor                  0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off  S:on 
apport                    0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
atd                       0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
.... and so on ....
```

You can enable / disable services for specific run-levels (or just turn them on and off) with:

```
# chkconfig -s <service> <state/runlevels>
```

for example:

```
# chkconfig -s gdm off
```

to turn it off completely,

```
# chkconfig -s gdm on
```

to turn it on with the defaultsm or

```
# chkconfig -s gdm 34
```

to only turn it on for run levels 3 and 4.

You'll usually find this command on RHEL based systems (CentOS, Fedora, etc).

***UPDATE***

*This is specific to Ubuntu and gdm / kdm / whatever.*

When gdm starts up it calls an upstart config file /etc/init/gdm.conf

This file then references /etc/X11/default-display-manager to see if it is the default display manager for the system - if it is then it starts.

The /etc/X11/default-display-manager just contains:

```
/usr/sbin/gdm
```

You can replace this with another display manager, or remove the file entirely and it won't start gdm.

A line from the /etc/init/gdm.conf file:

```
[ ! -f /etc/X11/default-display-manager -o "$(cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager 2>/dev/null)" = "/usr/sbin/gdm" ] || { stop; exit 0; }
```

It's saying "If the file /etc/X11/default-display-manager doesn't exist, or if it doesn't contain `/usr/sbin/gdm` then exit"

Comment: That didn't work. Just like rcconf, chkconfig does not list gdm as a service to be started at any run level. Yet, restarting, it loads. chkconfig -s gdm off did not prevent it from starting.

Comment: There is a link here also suggesting that chkconfig is not the appropriate tool to use: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1559266

Comment: I have never liked Ubuntu's startup - and Linux's in general.  It has always seems so messy and kludgy.  Give me FreeBSD's rcng any day.  Anyway - specific to Ubuntu's display manager you have what my edit shows...

Comment: +1 for correct after [edit] with details for upstart.

Answer (score 5):

I've always found the *sysv-rc-conf* tool very helpful, it has a very nice & easy to use interface.

install it like this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sysv-rc-conf
```

use it like this:

```
sudo sysv-rc-conf
```

Comment: I dont think that works for upstart services though..

Answer (score 4):

Simply take a look at `man 5 init` and you will find a more appropriate solution. Short example: Say we have a service called "foobar", so there would be a file called `/etc/init/foobar.conf` with its upstart configuration. Now you don't want to remove that file, nor to modify it -- but neither you want this service to run? So place an *override* file next to it: `/etc/init/foobar.override`, containing (optionally the header with the description and) instead the `start on` / `stop on` lines you place a line with one word: `manual`. This way you tell upstart to basically use the `foobar.conf`, but override the startup definition to only start that service when manually enforced (via `service foobar start` in our example).

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation would be to simply comment out all "start on" and "stop on" lines.  That worked well for me when I ran "initctl show-config" to see if the automatic startup of my program I wanted was disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Upstart is an *event-driven* init manager, and runlevels are not the primary mechanism for deciding when a service starts. Instead, services are started when all their dependencies are satisfied, which allows greater parallelism during boot, speeding up the boot process.

Using Ubuntu 11.04, I was able to disable GDM by editing the /etc/init/gdm.conf file, and removing all of the "start on" entries.  Here is my pre-edit:

```
start on (filesystem
          and started dbus
          and (drm-device-added card0 PRIMARY_DEVICE_FOR_DISPLAY=1
               or stopped udev-fallback-graphics))
stop on runlevel [016]
```

Here is my post-edit:

```
start on
stop on runlevel [016]
```

Comment: Correct; however, this is basically no better than just moving/removing the etc/init/gdm.conf file; I'm (still) amazed that manually editing the config file seems to be the only way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9416839&postcount=3

@Matt Jenkins

> I have never liked Ubuntu's startup - and Linux's in general. It has always seems so messy >and kludgy. Give me FreeBSD's rcng any day. Anyway - specific to Ubuntu's display manager >you have what my edit shows...

Arch Linux has a nice init system. However, systemd blows any other init system out of the planet.